# Comment overflow

Tags: bug, design

[image: comments overflow into sidebar]

Caused by [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222267/dog-who-has-escaped-an-animal-shelter-name/222272#comment473240_222267) overflowed comment which isn't line-broken.

Your table layout sucks! *shakes fist*

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Firefox 35.0. For me, it's line-broken.

Comment: I repro'd it in Chrome and Safari, so maybe it's webkit specific.

Comment: Webkit does handle word-breaks differently, and does allow unbreakable words (or bits of words) to extend outside borders. That link doesn't look right anyway. Far better to make a short link with tinyurl or something similar.

Comment: Happened to me in Chrome, also.

Answer (score 2):

The comment in question was made in [this posting.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222267/dog-who-has-escaped-an-animal-shelter-name)

The problem is nothing to do with line breaks. It is due to the fact that Kris failed to include the **http://** component of the URL. (NB — I am using Chrome as my browser.)

This is how he/she formatted it:

books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=runaway+*&year_start=1800&year_end‌​=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Crunaway%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0‌​%3B%3Brunaway%20slaves%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20slave%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20horse%‌​3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20negroes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20inflation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bruna‌​way%20match%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20horses%3B%2Cc0%3B%‌​3Brunaway%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20servant%3B%2Cc0

Appended as a comment below is the same link, this time including the **http://** prefix.

Comment: This is how the link [should have been formatted:](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=runaway+*&year_start=1800&year_end‌​=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Crunaway%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0‌​%3B%3Brunaway%20slaves%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20slave%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20horse%‌​3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20negroes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20inflation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bruna‌​way%20match%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20horses%3B%2Cc0%3B%‌​3Brunaway%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20servant%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: > Ngrams not found: runaway horse%‌​3B,c0, [runaway horse%‌​3B,c0], c0;%‌​3Brunaway and, [c0;%‌​3Brunaway and]

Comment: @bjb568 - But the link in my comment actually works; the fact that the Ngram tool doesn't find the search terms isn't relevant to your question as posed.

Comment: I think [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=runaway+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Crunaway%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brunaway%20slaves%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20slave%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20horse%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20negroes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20inflation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20match%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20horses%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20servant%3B%2Cc0) is the desired link.

Comment: Aha — I notice that your link starts with **https://** and not **http://** I think that clears up the conundrum. :)

Comment: +1 so I don't have to see this question being bumped again by "community".